# Symfony 1.4 switching to the production environment

Tags: apache, symfony-1.4, production-environment

The production environment of my symfony 1.4 app yields a 500 Internal server error.

tried reproducing the same error on my local machine and it basically yields the 500 internal server error as well along with the following message:

```
500 | Internal Server Error | sfConfigurationException
You must provide a "file" parameter for this logger

at ()
in SF_SYMFONY_LIB_DIR/log/sfFileLogger.class.php line 48 ...
  {

    if (!isset($options['file']))

    {

      throw new sfConfigurationException('You must provide a "file" parameter for this logger.');

    }


    if (isset($options['format']))
```

Visited my apache error logs and it states the following:

**[client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /Usrs, referer: http://localhost:8080/index.php**

One person suggested to check apache rewrite_module if it is enabled or not, and upon visiting httpd.conf file in my MAMP/conf/apache folder, there is

LOADMODULE rewrite_module...

and it is uncommented, which I am inferring that it is enabled.

In my index.php I have set:
$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', 'prod', true);

Where am I missing a trick here ? Your responses, constructive criticisms are welcome and appreciated!

Thanks!
Parijat

Answer (score 0):

Could you show us your `factories.yml` ? (in apps/my_apps/config/)

I guess you specified sth like that:

```
prod:
  logger:
    class: sfFileLogger
    param:
      level: debug
      file: %SF_LOG_DIR%/%SF_APP%_%SF_ENVIRONMENT%.log
```

But you forgot to define the **file** entry (ie: where the logger have to put the log informations). Check the doc [here](http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/05-Factories#chapter_05_logger).